# I want to install audio and video plugins

Tags: drivers

I recently dual booted ubuntu 17.10 with windows 10
At the time of installation i did not installed audio, video and  flash plugins
Now i want to install them
Can anybody tell me how to install them

Comment: install on what ??

Comment: Install on my Ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the following command lines

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

to install a meta-package that will bring a lot of packages with codecs etc for playing multimedia.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System **`Settings->Software & Update->additional drivers`** section and you can see something like this

[image]

Check/Uncheck based on your drivers.

Comment: @downvoter any reason ??

Comment: I did not downvote, I will upvote now. Your answer addresses the tag 'drivers', which is valuable information, but it does not address the question about 'audio and video plugins'.